# Calculating difference between dates and displaying the difference dynamically in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

i have been trying to calculate the difference between dates and store it in my model and display it.
I have created a model 'leave' with attributes 'fromdate','uptodate', 'calculateLeaves'.I am asking the user to enter the dates in fromdate and uptodate attributes.I want to dyanamically display the difference between these dates and store it in calculatedLeaves.

```
class leaveCreate(CreateView):
model = leave
fields = ['fromdate', 'uptodate']
def calculated_Leaves(self,fromdate,uptodate,calculatedLeaves):
    import pdb
    pdb.set_trace()
    d0 = leave.objects.filter(fromdate=fromdate,id=id())
    d1 = leave.objects.filter(uptodate=uptodate,id=id())
    delta = d0 - d1
    delta.save()
```

This is the view i have Written.But it doesn't work
What am i doing wrong? Please suggest anything that will help me.

Comment: what doesn't work exactly ? the dates conversion/formating, or the view ?

Answer (score 0):

```
def day_diff(from_date, to_date):
  diff = to_date - from_date
  days_in_between = diff.days
  return days_in_between
```

I think it may work

from_date & to_date are date objects